# changing the structure of javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My current object is of the form:

```
[{Vol:'AB', freq:[{used:4786, avail:1319, res:249}]}
,{Vol:'CD', freq:[{used:1101, avail:412, res:674}]}]
```

I need to change it to the form:

```
[{Vol:'AB', freq:{used:4786, avail:1319, res:249}}
,{Vol:'CD', freq:{used:1101, avail:412, res:674}}]
```

How can this be done.

Comment: This is exceedingly trivial, please learn a modicum about Javascript arrays and objects, try something, and if you're still having problems, then post

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Please remind yourself that at some stage this would have been beyond your coding skills. We all had to start at the basics, and not everyone has the support and resources to make learning easy. Ostracising people for asking any level question does nothing to help. Please keep these types of comments to yourself in future.

Comment: @Blindman67 This site is polluted with too many of these *exact* kinds of questions -- help me get something out of a Javascript object or JSON.  The OP made *no* effort, or at least showed none, and not just no coding effort, but apparently no research effort.  So no, I won't keep my comments to myself under such circumstances.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty There is a down vote button if you do not approve of a post. Have you considered that many questions are asked by very young people and that even very trivial condemnation can have a significant impact? Please alway show respect to all.

Comment: @Blindman67 There is no rule that you can't down-vote (which I did) *and* comment.  We cannot be concerned about fragile egos when trying to weed out bad questions on SO.

Comment: I have got my answer..if you people want i can delete my question from here!! Don't take it personally @GeorgeJempty

Comment: @madhuri You can't now that there is an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
obj.map( s => (s.freq = s.freq[0], s) );
```

Explanation

- Iterate the array using `map`
- Replace each items `freq`'s array with its first item

**Demo**

```js
var input = [{
  Vol: 'AB',
  freq: [{
    used: 4786,
    avail: 1319,
    res: 249
  }]
}, {
  Vol: 'CD',
  freq: [{
    used: 1101,
    avail: 412,
    res: 674
  }]
}];

input = input.map(s => (s.freq = s.freq[0], s));

console.log(input);
```

Comment: @gurvinder372  I like the syntax  s => (s.freq = s.freq[0], s) . It's new to me! Does the callback return s?

Comment: @Faly Yes, final expression after last comma is returned.